# Django : Prevent search engine indexing of internal pages/links

Tags: python, django

I have a Django project where I have internal pages to monitor data. I don't want the search engine to index those pages neither want to disclose the link to the internet. Can this be achieved?

Comment: as @dietbacon has answered , this is done with robots.txt if you don't want a search engine to index them you have to use robots.txt if you don't want anyone to know that such a link exists, that cannot be prevented with 100% confidence. Password protect those pages instead.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is the robots.txt file, to hide it from robots:

> The robots exclusion standard, also known as the robots exclusion
>   protocol or robots.txt protocol, is a standard used by websites to
>   communicate with web crawlers and other web robots. The standard
>   specifies the instruction format to be used to inform the robot about
>   which areas of the website should not be processed or scanned. Robots
>   are often used by search engines to categorize and archive web sites,
>   or by webmasters to proofread source code.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard

To not allow other people to enter, you make a check to see if it's your ip connecting to the view, otherwise you return a 404 or whatever you want. (you can check that in the request's meta)

Comment: Is the robots.txt file accessible to anyone? If that is the case, then one can find about the list of internal links.

Comment: @anon it is, but it's the standard way to tell crawlers not to go to that page. To block users from a page you'd have to have a list of allowed IP's and block all others, return a 404.